# С++ Выделение места под вектор

Tags: c++, классы, vector, конструктор, инициализация

Нужно в конструторе инициализировать вектор элементов. При такой реализации выводит segfault. Как мне выделить место под вектор в конструторе класса?

```
private:
    int c;
    std::vector<int> b;
public:
    a() : c(0) { b[3] = 5; }
    int getC() { return c; }
    void setC(int d) { c = d; } 
};

int  main() {
    a var;
    var.setC(1);
    printf("111 - %d\n", var.getC());
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну сначала дайте вектору нужное количество элементов...

Например:

```
a() : c(0), b(4) { b[3] = 5; }
```

Здесь вектор инициализируется четырьмя нулевыми элементами, так что `b[3] = 5;` приобретает смысл...

Для двумерного вектора

```
vector<vector<int>> b;
```

инициализация выглядит так:

```
b(4,vector<int>(4));
```

т.е. 4 элемента, каждый из которых - вектор из 4 элементов...

Comment: Спасибо, заработало. Я почему-то думал, что вектор сам определяет сколько места нужно выделить, и раз я указал b[3], то он места под 3 элемента и выделит.
Теперь появился еще один вопрос)
Как то же самое провернуть с двумерным вектором?
`std::vector<std::vector<int>> b; a() : c(0), b(4)(4) { b[3][2] = 5; }`

Comment: См. дополнение в ответе.

Comment: Дай бог здоровья, очень выручили!